# how to write emitted tuple into kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-producer-api

Application is reading messages from one Kafka topic and after storing in MongoDB and doing some validations it is writing into another topic. Here I am facing issue like application is going into infinite loop.
Code I have is below:

```java
Hosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
String zkRoot = "/brokers/topics" ;
String clientRequestID = "reqtest";
String clientPendingID = "pendtest";
SpoutConfig kafkaRequestConfig = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts,"reqtest",zkRoot,clientRequestID);
SpoutConfig kafkaPendingConfig = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts,"pendtest",zkRoot,clientPendingID);

kafkaRequestConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
kafkaPendingConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
KafkaSpout kafkaRequestSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaRequestConfig);
KafkaSpout kafkaPendingSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaPendingConfig);

MongoBolt mongoBolt = new MongoBolt() ;
DeviceFilterBolt deviceFilterBolt = new DeviceFilterBolt() ;
KafkaRequestBolt kafkaReqBolt = new KafkaRequestBolt() ;
abc1DeviceBolt abc1DevBolt = new abc1DeviceBolt() ;
DefaultTopicSelector defTopicSelector = new DefaultTopicSelector(xyzKafkaTopic.RESPONSE.name()) ;
KafkaBolt kafkaRespBolt = new KafkaBolt()
    .withTopicSelector(defTopicSelector)
    .withTupleToKafkaMapper(new FieldNameBasedTupleToKafkaMapper()) ;

TopologyBuilder topoBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
topoBuilder.setSpout(xyzComponent.KAFKA_REQUEST_SPOUT.name(), kafkaRequestSpout);
topoBuilder.setSpout(xyzComponent.KAFKA_PENDING_SPOUT.name(), kafkaPendingSpout);
topoBuilder.setBolt(xyzComponent.KAFKA_PENDING_BOLT.name(),
    deviceFilterBolt, 1)
    .shuffleGrouping(xyzComponent.KAFKA_PENDING_SPOUT.name()) ;
topoBuilder.setBolt(xyzComponent.abc1_DEVICE_BOLT.name(),
    abc1DevBolt, 1)
    .shuffleGrouping(xyzComponent.KAFKA_PENDING_BOLT.name(),
        xyzDevice.abc1.name()) ;
topoBuilder.setBolt(xyzComponent.MONGODB_BOLT.name(), 
    mongoBolt, 1)
    .shuffleGrouping(xyzComponent.abc1_DEVICE_BOLT.name(),
        xyzStreamID.KAFKARESP.name());
topoBuilder.setBolt(xyzComponent.KAFKA_RESPONSE_BOLT.name(),
    kafkaRespBolt, 1)
    .shuffleGrouping(xyzComponent.abc1_DEVICE_BOLT.name(),
        xyzStreamID.KAFKARESP.name());

Config config = new Config() ;
config.setDebug(true);
config.setNumWorkers(1);

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
config.put(KafkaBolt.KAFKA_BROKER_PROPERTIES, props);

LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
try{
    cluster.submitTopology("demo", config, topoBuilder.createTopology());
}
```

In the above code, `KAFKA_RESPONSE_BOLT` is writing the data into topic.
`abc1_DEVICE_BOLT` is feeding this `KAFKA_RESPONSE_BOLT` by emitting the data like:

```java
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer ofd) {
    Fields respFields = IoTFields.getKafkaResponseFieldsRTEXY();
    ofd.declareStream(IoTStreamID.KAFKARESP.name(), respFields);
}

@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    List<Object> newTuple = new ArrayList<Object>() ;
    String params  = tuple.getStringByField("params") ;
    newTuple.add(3, params);
    ----
    collector.emit(IoTStreamID.KAFKARESP.name(), newTuple);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "like application is going into infinite loop"? What behavior do you get? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, the same input message is reading again and again from pendtest topic, i am expecting i have to place the read input into resptest topic by modifying some structure and store in mongo

Comment: i am able to modify and store it into mongo but not able to write to topic

Comment: Any messages that time out? This would explain reading the same message over and over again... Any errors in the log files?

Answer (score 1):

I have been bothered by the same question for a long time, the answer is very simple... you will not believe it .

As far as I understand,implementation of `KafkaBolt` have to receive tuples has field name of “message”，no matter it is a Bolt or Spout.So you have to do some changes to your code, which I have not seen carefully.(But I believe this would help!)

The specific reason are said at https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-storm-user/201409.mbox/%3C6AF1CAC6-60EA-49D9-8333-0343777B48A7@andrashatvani.com%3E

Comment: Could you please help me how did you fixed this problem. I'm facing the same. thanks!